# Cannot open Merge Editor in VS Code for resolving conflicts when merging branches of .ipynb notebook

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I recently started getting an issue after merging branches of a .ipynb notebook in VS Code.
A merge conflict is detected, but I cannot open the built-in Merge Editor of VS Code. I think my config might be messed up after I recently tried to install nbdime and uninstalled it again.

I'm quite a noob at doing merges with notebooks in VS Code, so please bear with me.

Steps to follow, all done in VS Code user interface:

1. Create a new branch from main, called dev.
2. Merge branch feat_1 into dev
3. Pop-up appears:
   [merge_confl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQrN.png)
4. I click on "Show Changes" and nothing happens
5. `git merge --abort` and then repeat steps 2 & 3, but I click on "Open Git Log" and nothing happens.

Here is what's inside the .gitconfig file:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = 
    helper = !/usr/bin/gh auth git-credential
[user]
    email = yyy@aaa.com
    name = yyy aaa
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --merge $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED
```

I am using a Linux system. I have tried doing the same in the terminal:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```
$ git merge feature_restructure_prediction
Auto-merging file_a.ipynb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file_a.ipynb
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

When I do `git mergetool` the VS Code app opens and tries to open file_a.ipynb but an error from VS Code appears:
"Unable to open file_a.ipynb. Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 123"
I understand its somehow trying to open a .ipynb and expecting JSON, and these `<<<<<<<<<< HEAD >>>>>>>>>>>>`paragraphs are appearing and messing it up.

I also have these settings (amongst others) enabled in VS Code:
"git.mergeEditor": true
"merge-conflict.codeLens.enabled": true

I've searched stackoverflow and the 'net but haven't found a solution.